# Expanding $M(t) = \dfrac {0.3e^t}{1-0.7e^t}$ as a sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I know the formula $\displaystyle \dfrac {1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$, but I am unable to get my expression to the form of $\dfrac {1}{1-x}$. I can of course write it as $0.3e^t\dfrac {1}{1-0.7e^t}$, but I forgot how to manipulate it the rest of the way.

Comment: Please clarify if setting $x = 0.7e^t$, i.e.
$$M(t) = 0.3e^t \cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty (0.7^k e^{tk})$$
is not enough.

Comment: @AlexR Oh I'm sorry I just confused myself, mistakenly believed the nonsense that I needed to have $(0.7e)^t$ in order to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
0.3e^t\dfrac {1}{1-0.7e^t} 
= 0.3e^t\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (0.7e^t)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}0.3\cdot0.7^ke^{t(k+1)}
$$
for $t$ such that $0.7e^t<1$.

Comment: in your last equality you seem to be saying that $(0.7)^k  =0.7$ for all $k$

Comment: @ WW1 I fixed the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{1-x}-1 =\frac{1- (1-x)}{1-x} = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance, but how would this simplify things? $0.3e^t \ne 1 - 0.7e^t$ - mind the $\exp$...

Comment: @AlexR : I thought OP may have been confused about the presence of the variable in the numerator. Scaling by a constant will make $x$ as I have written (I presume you mean to say $0.3e^t \neq 0.7 e^t$).

Answer (score 1):

The identification $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ only holds when $|x|<1$. Then

$$\frac{0.3e^t}{1-0.7e^t}=\frac{0.3}{0.7}\cdot\frac{0.7e^t}{1-0.7e^t}=\frac37\sum_{k=1}^\infty(0.7e^t)^k,\quad t<\ln\frac{10}7$$

and

$$\frac{0.3}{0.7}\cdot\frac{0.7e^t}{1-0.7e^t}=-\frac37\cdot\frac1{1-(0.7e^t)^{-1}}=-\frac37\sum_{k=0}^\infty(0.7e^t)^{-k},\quad t>\ln\frac{10}7$$